# MySQL - problems updating a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which I want to update with values from another table, and  I am using the following code:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Value = (
    SELECT TableB.Value2
    FROM TableB
    WHERE TableA.id=TableB.ta_id
);
```

Despite the fact that TableA.id is the primary key of tableA, I keep getting the following error:

Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your SQL IDE does not allow updating all records of a table. It is a save switch. Turn it off in the settings.

Comment: use `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your not using the Where statement in your primary query. 
In your case, it would modify all your table.If it is what you want to do, You can either desactivate the safe mode of mysql or doing an always true condition like

```
UPDATE TableA,TableB
SET TableA.Value = TableB.Value2
WHERE TableA.id = TableB.ta_id;
```

Comment: I'm trying to update every row in TableA that has another row in TableB such that TableA.id=TableB.ta_id. Not sure if this means modifying all my table? If so, is this bad practice?

Comment: It doesnt mean to modify all your table, only the one that are in the TableB . So instead of `WHERE TableA.id is not null` , just put `WHERE TableA.id = TableB.ta_id`. In that way, it will only modify the rows that are also in TableB

Comment: It gives me an error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'TableB.ta_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: try changing `Update TableA`  to `Update TableA,TableB` and `Value` by `TableA.Value`

Comment: Yes, I still get 1175.

Comment: alright so you get 2 choice, first you do `Set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` or you need to add your primary key in the Where statement . I dont know if Table.id was your primary key, if yes just try the Set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES and restart your mysql.